# Getting Username By Id

Tags: php, mysqli

Could someone help me out as i'm new to PHP and MYSQLI

I'm trying to make a comment system for my movies page example below

Database Structure

Comments Table

```
id          int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
movie_id    int(11)         No  None        
user_id     int(11)         No  None        
message     varchar(1000)   No  None        
timestamp   timestamp       No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Users Table

```
id          int(50)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
username    varchar(50)     No  None
email       varchar(100)    No  None        
group       varchar(20)     No  None        
password    varchar(20)     No  None
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$comments = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
while($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($comments)) {
?>

<a href="www.mysite.com/movie.php?id=<?php echo $comment['movie_id']; ?>"><?php echo $comment['message']; ?></a>

<?php 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So what i want to do is get `username` from `Users table` by using `user_id` from `Comments table`

Could someone show me how to get them and how to echo them please.

Comment: RTFM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: ^...and a `"FABULOUS"` one at that.

Comment: While Marc B's response could be read as slightly abrasive, he's right on the money. You ought to learn a few things about SQL if you're going to be using SQL databases. Joins are not a head against the wall, hard to figure out thing (at least not in their most basic forms, like what's required here). You're trying to do something particular while avoiding the establishment of fundamental understanding. Learning takes time. Don't try to fast-track your way to an application--you'll hate life trying to maintain and debug it later.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
    `comments` c
JOIN `users` u
    ON c.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Within your while loop the user name will be available as $comment['username'].
You can find more about mysql join here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
"SELECT * FROM users,comments WHERE users.id=comments.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC"
```

This should work.